# Shell Script for counting down passed argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

So I was working on a project tonight and assumed based on my poor understanding that the requirement was to create a script to take a number and count down to 1 with commas on the same line.

A few people here introduced me to the seq command and I was on my way.

Turns out it needs to take the variable integer from a command line argument.

What I have now:

```
#!/bin/bash
#countdown

read -p "Enter a Number great than 1: " counter

seq -s, $counter -1
```

Needs to work by taking an argument after the line, such as /assign1p1 5 and then outputting 5,4,3,2,1

I've seen the $1 used as an argument marker?  Is that how to work from it?

Comment: Be careful using `seq`. While that's what people in the real world would do, it may not be what your project requires. +10 for cleverness, -several_million for being a smart-a**, as Zaphod would say :-)

Comment: I strongly encourage you to read the manual for bash either by typing `man bash` or `info bash` or by reading this: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command-line arguments passed to your script are `$1`, `$2`, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

seq -s, $1 1
echo
```

If you want to make this more robust you might want to verify that the user passed in the correct number of arguments, which is the variable `$#`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( $# != 1 )); then
    echo "Usage: $0 num" >&2
    exit 1
fi

seq -s, $1 1
echo
```

Comment: Indeed sir, I got that working while I was waiting.  I just need validation now for multiple arguments and non positive integers

Comment: Wow I can't begin to thank you enough.  I was actually half way to that in the interim.  I keep getting little pieces here and there and then going back to the vmbox to try a few things, then you guys drop even more awesome knowledge on me.

Comment: how can I get it to echo out something with the incorrect type or number or arguments?

thinking of doing if (($# >=2)) for the type and not sure how to ask if the argument exceeds the $1 level, stop

Answer (score 1):

### Use Three Arguments

The correct call to `seq` for your use case is:

> seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST

To decrement your starting value down to 1 using the defined separator, try something similar to this example:

```
$ set -- 5
$ seq -s, $1 -1 1
5,4,3,2,1
```

Obviously, the call to `set` won't be needed inside the script, but is a great way to test at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments passed to the script from the command line include : $0, $1, $2, $3 . . .

$0 is the name of the script itself, $1 is the first argument, $2 the second, $3 the third, and so forth. [2] After $9, the arguments must be enclosed in brackets, for example, ${10}, ${11}, ${12}.

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you do not want to use `seq`

```
a=$1
for (( b = a; b > 0; b-- ))
do
  (( b == a )) || printf ,
  printf $b
done
```